# Ruby mode in emacs: how can I choose which version of ruby is ran when running irb?

Tags: ruby, emacs

I have several version of ruby installed and when I run "run-ruby" on emacs it launches me the irb associated with ruby 1.8.7, while I'd like to use the irb from ruby 1.9.3.
Does someone know how to configure that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using `inf-ruby.el`, then you need to change the `ruby-program-name` variable to corresponding program. Default value is `irb --inf-ruby-mode`, and I think, that you need to also specify the `--inf-ruby-mode` command-line option.

Answer (score 5):

also check out [rvm.el](https://github.com/senny/rvm.el). If you are switching, even just once, install [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io//) (rvm) and switching is easy, and just as easy, in emacs too.

Two birds with one stone.